# How to get r to display a specific observation?

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm currently playing around with a dummy dataset (trying to learn R) and I re-coded the gender of a specific observation. I wanted to see if my command had worked, but I couldn't figure out what code to use to get R to display a specific observation. I know I can just open the dataset and look through it, but I wanted to know what function I could use to bring up specific observations in datasets. In this case I re-coded the gender using the below code:

```
linelist <- linelist %>% 
  mutate(gender = replace(gender, case_id == "2195", "Female"))
```

What code do I use to get R to display (on the console) the gender of case id 2195?

Thanks!

Comment: Given that `linelist` is your `data.frame`, how about `linelist[linelist$case_id == 2195, ]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `filter` for the observation you want.

```
linelist %>% 
  mutate(gender = replace(gender, case_id == "2195", "Female")) %>%
  filter(case_id == "2195") %>%
  select(case_id, gender) %>% # Optional, will only print the case_id and gender columns 
  print() # Optional, can also use View() to use the RStudio pane
```

Note that I did not assign the result to `linelist`, as I assumed you only wanted to see if it worked, and *then* save it.